# Querying Delegated Administrators

Tags: soql, metadata

Is there a way to query a list of delegated administrators? I looked in the list of objects available to query in Force.com Explorer and can't find any objects that look like they would have this information.

I'm open to any approach to get a list of delegated admins: using the metadata api, Apex code or SOQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally got an official response from Salesforce that Delegated Administrators is not available via the API.

You can see a list of all unsupported metadata types here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm

Answer (score 3):

I'm the product manager for Delegated Admin at Salesforce.  We are investing and giving Delegated Admin some much-needed love.  We are currently working on making delegated admin and the delegate groups available via the Tooling API.

Work is still in progress, but I'm confident you will see this in the Spring '23 release here are the release notes https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_permissions_delegate_group_api.htm&type=5&release=242

Over the next couple of releases, you will see Permission Set Groups in Delegated Admin and some other enhancements coming.  Thank you for your feedback.  And thank you to Daniel Hoechst for pointing me to this question so I could provide a product update.

Comment: Welcome to SfSE! No signature are taglines are required here (and they are actively discouraged). The model here is pure Q & A. Also, it might be worth adding a bit of info in your profile about your role to help make it clear you are an authoritative source.

Comment: Great to hear it is finally getting some attention ! Delegated Administration has always been a pain on User Management automation efforts side, and very difficult to explain to management why was that so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query using SOQL, then I am afraid there is no way of getting hold of delegated administrators. There is a "DelegatedApproverId" field on the user object that you can query, if that helps.

Anup

Comment: Do you know of any way to get at the Delegated Admins in code or metadata api? We have a really big org with lots of delegated admins and I'd like to generate a report. I'm not interested in Delegated Approvers.