# How do I assign Delegated Administration via DML or query it via SOQL?

Tags: soql, dml, delegated-admin

I would like to assign power-users to be admins of Delegated Administration groups a bit easier than the click-through manual process.

Is there a way I can query admins via SOQL or assign admins via DML?

I can do these assignments for other setup-type operations (`PermissionSetAssignment`, `Profile`, `UserTerritory2Association`, `UserRole`, `GroupMember`).  Is there a way to do it for Delegated Administration Groups?  If so, how?

If not, is there any other programmatic API for user assignments to delegate admin groups?

Comment: Looks like the documentation is misleading. Apparently, no official way to support this at all that I could find. That's really unfortunate.

Comment: @sfdcfox So the choices are either do it by hand or with a headless browser...  Too bad

Comment: And a eight year old idea to go with it: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IKQz ... Seems like it's a low priority thing.

Comment: related to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129/querying-delegated-administrators

Answer (score 1):

you cannot add/delete delegated admin programmatically.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm

it mean delegated admin is metadata(not sobject data). but salesforce does not support it (yet).